# Get the element count of this array?

Tags: perl

I have this array and for the life of me I cannot find out how to return the element count.

I have looked through perl sites but can't seem to find the answer.
How do I return the element count for the following?

```perl
my $animals = [ "dog", "cat", "canary", "mouse", ];

foreach my $i (0..$animals){ #this does not work
print $animals->[$i]
}
```

Comment: `$animals` is an array ref. you need to deference it to then use it as an array `@$animals`

Comment: You should also note that @$animals will give you a count of how many elements are in the array. However since the array starts at 0 you will need to subtract 1 to get the last index position.

Comment: Thanks I find Perl a litlle bit cryptic compared to pascal. I used scalar @$animals and it returned 4. Cheers.

Comment: yeah it will return 4 as your array has 4 elements. However arrays start with index 0. So if you are calling them by index then it will be 0, 1, 2, 3. that is the index location of your 4 inputs. So when you get the size of the arry you need to substract one. I have added an example as an answer.

Comment: Of course, for this example you don't need the indices at all. `for my $animal (@$animals) { print $animal }` works just as well, if not better.

Comment: Cryptic, you say? `print for @$animals` ;-)

Comment: `0 .. $#{$animals}` can be also used if you need indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an array reference with

```
my $animals = [];
```

So if you want to do array like actions on it then you need to dereference it. You can deference it using either of the two formats

```
my $count = @$animals;
```

or

```
my $count = @{$animals};
```

For example

```
perl -e '
 my $animals = [ "dog", "cat", "canary", "mouse", ]; 
 print $animals->[$_], "\n" foreach (0 .. $#$animals);
'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
dog
cat
canary
mouse
```

However this is giving you a count of the elements which you then iterate over using the index position of the array. You can do this much simpler in perl by saying

```
foreach my $animal (@$animals){
    print $animal, "\n";
}
```

Using the above example perl will iterate through the array loading each element into the variable `$animal` which you can then print.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I return the element count?

You have an `arrayref`. Just dereference it and use [**scalar**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) to count elements in array.

```
my $animals = [ "dog", "cat", "canary", "mouse", ];
print scalar @$animals;
```

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
my @a=qw(dog,cat,canary,mouse);
my $size=$#a+1;
print"$size\n";
```